# google-apps-script cannot read array value ("typeError: "cannot read property "1" )

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make my code sending an email by referring to my google sheet data. Im using Apps Script and here is the code. However, as I run my function "sendEmail()", I got "typeError: "cannot read property "1" of undefined(line 17)".

Code line 17

```
var currentEmail = rows[i][1];
```

Here is the full code.

```
var ss = "1kuTkOuCd-wKTS2564oHdxALFbFo-IeyjzToYYhB6NrQ";
var SheetName = "FormResp";

function getRows(){
  var rangeName = 'FormResp!A2:E'; 
  var rows = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss, rangeName).values;
  return rows;
}

function sendEmails() {
  var ss_1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss);
  var sheet = ss_1.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 0;i<=lr;i++){
    rows=getRows();
    var currentEmail = rows[i][1];
    var startingdate = rows[i][3];
    var endingdate = rows[i][4];
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,"Thank You for Applying Leave via Leave form: your request leave starting" + startingdate + "until" + endingdate,"Hello");
    
  }
  
}


function testgetrow(){
  var nama = getRows();
  var x = ""; 
}
```

I do make a test function "testgetrow()" to check my data, and I do manage to run the function without any error and I do confirm that there is values in my getRows() function.

my getRows() function working, and there is a value in the array as shown in the picture below.

[image: there us value in 0]

Comment: This `for (var i = 0;i<=lr;i++)` should be `for (var i = 0;i<lr;i++)`

Comment: Using ranges like `A2:E` is a  problem because you end up with a lot of null lines at the bottom which have to be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do it any way you wish but this seems a lot simpler to me.

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kuTkOuCd-wKTS2564oHdxALFbFo-IeyjzToYYhB6NrQ");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('FormResp');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,5);
  const vs=rg.getValues(); 
  vs.forEach(r=>{  
    var currentEmail = r[1];
    var startingdate = r[3];
    var endingdate = r[4];
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,"Thank You for Applying Leave via Leave form: your request leave starting" + startingdate + "until" + endingdate,"Hello");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The main problem is that you have not declared properly the variable `rows` in your line 16 `rows=getRows();` because you forgot to use the keyword `var`. Change that line with `var rows = getRows()` and try it again.

### Take a look

- You are mixing [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) with [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script). I recommend you to pick one and stay there to have a clear and less confusing code.
- Try use less functions if they are not really necessary, as @Cooper suggested, you can define the variable `rows` with [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) that can handle `A1 notation` `ranges` and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Define properly your `range` in `A1 notation`: if you write `A2:E`, your `range` goes from column `A`, row `2` until column `E`, row `1000`. You have to add the number of the last row in your `range`, for example `A2:E10`.
- With the last change, you do not have to calculate the last row, you can simply use `rows.length`.
- It is not necessary to have the `id` of the `spreadsheet` if your script is a [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) and not a [Standalone Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) with [getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)

I attach you a snippet of the code:

```
var sheetName = "FormResp";
var spreadsheet_id = "1kuTkOuCd-wKTS2564oHdxALFbFo-IeyjzToYYhB6NrQ";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet_id).getSheetByName(sheetName)

function sendEmails() {
  var rangeName = 'A1:B9'; 
  var rows = ss.getRange(rangeName).getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++){
    var currentEmail = rows[i][1];
    var startingdate = rows[i][3];
    var endingdate = rows[i][4];
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,"Thank You for Applying Leave via Leave form: your request leave starting" + startingdate + "until" + endingdate,"Hello");
  }
}
```

I hope that it helps you!

### References

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [Standalone Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

Comment: That's not the main problem